# Defining window based on multiple columns

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType, StructType, StructField, \
    MapType, FloatType, BooleanType, DoubleType, LongType, DateType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sqlc = SQLContext(sc)

schema = StructType([
    StructField('key', StructType([
                StructField('event_name', StringType()),
                StructField('event_type', StringType())])), 
    StructField('uuid', StringType(), False),
    StructField('timestamp', LongType(), False),
    ])

df_test = sqlc.createDataFrame([
    ["1",['name_1', "type_1"], 1532428811 ], 
    ["1", ['name_2', "type_2"],1532428812], 
    ["1", ['name_2', "type_1"],1532428813], 
    ["2",['name_3', "type_3"], 1532428814],
    ["2",['name_4', "type_3"], 1532428815], 
    ["2",['name_5', "type_3"], 1532428880]], 
    schema= schema)
```

```
+----+----------------+----------+
|uuid|             key| timestamp|
+----+----------------+----------+
|   1|[name_1, type_1]|1532428811|
|   1|[name_2, type_2]|1532428812|
|   1|[name_2, type_1]|1532428813|
|   2|[name_3, type_3]|1532428814|
|   2|[name_4, type_3]|1532428815|
|   2|[name_5, type_3]|1532428880|
+----+----------------+----------+
```

I would like to group the data so that I have a row for each uuid when the difference between any timestamps (from the same uuid) is less than a cutoff threshold and the event_types are the same.

Additionally, I want to keep the start and end of the timestamps to be the min and max timestamps of the rows that satisfied the conditions.

The output should look like this, assuming the cutoff threshold is 50 (note the last row below is got separated from the one to the last because the timestamp differences is > 50):

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|uuid|      key                                                  | start     | end       |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
|   1|[[name_1|type_1, 1532428811], [name_2|type_1, 1532428813]] |1532428811 | 1532428813|
|   1|[[name_2|type_2, 1532428812]]                              |1532428812 | 1532428812|
|   2|[[name_3|type_3, 1532428814], [name_4|type_3, 1532428815]] |1532428814 | 1532428815|
|   2|[[name_5|type_3, 1532428880]]                              |1532428880 | 1532428880|
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+
```